# How to get a hold of dialog stack on v4 node SDK BOT

Tags: node.js, botframework

I'm used to v3 node botbuilder sdk so I have a middleware where I look at the dialog stack and do operation I needed as follows.

V3 middleware which knows dialog stack:-

```
bot.use({
    botbuilder: function (session, next) {

        if (session.dialogStack()&& session.dialogStack().length <= 0 ) {
            // Do something is dialog stack is empty.
        }

    },
    send: function (event, next) {
        if (event.type != "typing" && event.type != "endOfConversation") {
            logUserConversation("Botoutput", event);
        }
        next();
    }
});
```

V4 middleware where I need to use dialog stack to perform some operations.

```
adapter.use(async (turnContext, next) => {
            // pre-processing of the current incoming activity
            turnContext.onSendActivities(async (sendContext, activities, nextSend) => {
                // console.log(`pre-processing of outgoing activities`);
                await nextSend();

         ***//Need to know the dialog stack here.***


            });
            await next();
        });
```

I looked up on turnContext object but there is no indication if dialog stack. I can see [DialogContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-dialogs/dialogcontext?view=botbuilder-ts-latest) object has a 'stack' property but, not sure how to use in my middleware.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add the activities.filter method to retrieve the passed thru data and you're good to go.

```js
const conversationState = new ConversationState(memoryStorage);
const userState = new UserState(memoryStorage);

adapter.use(async (turnContext, next) => {

    const userActivity = turnContext.activity;
    if (userActivity.from.role === 'user' && turnContext.activity.text.length > 0) {
        console.log('From user: ', userActivity);
    }

    turnContext.onSendActivities(async (sendContext, activities, nextSend) => {
        await nextSend();

        activities.filter(a => a.type !== 'typing' && a.type !== 'endOfConversation').forEach(a => console.log('From bot: ', a));
    });

    await next();
});
```

Hope of help!

Comment: I think you didn't get my question right. I was talking about accessing dialog stack and not looping over activities data.

Comment: @vijay, I have updated the code to better match the v3 code you provided. The if captures activity coming in from the user. The onSendActivities captures any activity that is not typing or an endOfConversation type from the bot. This collectively reflects the dialog stack.